Prevent the app from closing when the back button is pressed
After scanning barcode When I press the back button, my app closes. I am using Flutter and Kotlin code for barcode scanning. It should go to the home page, which is TestScreen, but it doesn't.
Here is my MainActivity.kt file
 package com.samsung.promoter
    
import android.app.ActivityManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.zxing.Result
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView

class MainActivity : FlutterFragmentActivity(), ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private val CHANNEL_OPEN_APP = "com.samsung.promoter/open_app"
    private val CHANNEL_SCAN_BARCODE = "com.samsung.promoter/scanBarcode"
    private var mScannerView: ZXingScannerView? = null
    private var resultCallback: MethodChannel.Result? = null

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        val openAppChannel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL_OPEN_APP)
        val scanBarcodeChannel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL_SCAN_BARCODE)

        openAppChannel.setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "openApp") {
                bringAppToForeground()
            }
        }

        scanBarcodeChannel.setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "scanBarcode") {
                resultCallback = result
                startBarcodeScanner()
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun bringAppToForeground() {
        val activityManager = getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        val appTasks = activityManager.appTasks
        for (task in appTasks) {
            if (task.taskInfo.baseActivity?.packageName == packageName) {
                task.moveToFront()
                return
            }
        }
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun startBarcodeScanner() {
        if (mScannerView == null) {
            mScannerView = ZXingScannerView(this)
        }
        mScannerView?.let {
            it.setResultHandler(this)
            setContentView(it)
            it.startCamera()
        }
    }

 override fun onBackPressed() {
    // Stop the barcode scanner
    mScannerView?.stopCamera()

    // Navigate back to the TestScreen
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}

    override fun handleResult(rawResult: Result) {
        // Send the scanned barcode result back to Flutter
        resultCallback?.success(rawResult.text)

        // Stop the camera
        mScannerView?.stopCamera()
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        // Finish the activity and go back to Flutter
//        finish()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mScannerView?.stopCamera()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mScannerView?.startCamera()
    }
}

Here is my test_screen.dart
class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  String barcode="Unkown";

   TestScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const platform = MethodChannel('com.samsung.promoter/scanBarcode');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar( title: Text("TEst"),),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async {
            try {
              barcode = await platform.invokeMethod('scanBarcode');
              print("BarCode ${barcode}");
            } on PlatformException catch (e) {
              barcode = "Failed to scan barcode: '${e.message}'.";
            }
          
          }, child: Text("Test")),

          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async {
            var result = await LocalAuthService.authenticate();
          }, child: Text("Athenticate"))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


I think you are using same activity for configuring flutter and scanner you need launch a new activity for scanner then on close you can just close the scanner activity.
